# Can I monitor COM calls to my VisualBasic 6 ActiveX control?

Tags: com, vb6, activex

I wrote a little ActiveX control in VisualBasic 6 which is going to be used as a plugin for some 3rd party framework. The framework expects that my control exposes a few properties and methods. It all seems to work well except that one of my properties seems to be ignored.

In C++, I could put debug statement into the reimplementations of `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames` and `IDispatch::Invoke` to see which members the framework attempts to access - maybe the documentation is wrong, and it's expecting a different property name or something.

Is it possible to monitor the accesses to COM properties/methods in Visual Basic 6, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add logging of some form in the methods/properties in question. I don't think you can hook the lower level COM calls though.
For the logging, you can use `OutputDebugString()`.

Comment: Right, I'm using OutputDebugString already. However, how can I print debug output in case some property is queried? After all, the property is a plain 'public FooProperty As String' in my VisualBasic 6 code.

Comment: Explicitly make it a public property rather than a public variable. `Public Property Get Wibble() As String` (and `Public Property Let Wibble(ByVal NewWibble As String)` if you want it to be writable)

Comment: Ah, excellent - that seems to work! I didn't know this was possible, thanks!

Comment: Public variables (in VB6) are implicitly converted to simple Get and Set Properties when exposed via COM.

Answer (score 2):

There's a rather old 'Hardcore Visual Basic' book around that teaches you exactly how to implement IUnknown, IDispatch etc. in VB5/6.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for mentioning this, I'll definately have a look!